# Why the command is giving that output and what do in this case?

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, dpkg, fonts, configuration

First, I ran:

```
sudo dpkg --verify



??5?????? c /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mozc-server
??5?????? c /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
??5?????? c /etc/casper.conf
??5?????? c /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
??5??????   /sbin/start-stop-daemon
??5?????? c /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
??5?????? c /etc/apport/blacklist.d/thunderbird
??5?????? c /etc/apport/native-origins.d/thunderbird
??5?????? c /etc/thunderbird/syspref.js
??5?????? c /etc/host.conf
??5?????? c /etc/fonts/conf.avail/25-arphic-ukai-render.conf
??5?????? c /etc/fonts/conf.avail/25-ttf-arphic-ukai-render.conf
??5?????? c /etc/fonts/conf.avail/35-arphic-ukai-aliases.conf
??5?????? c /etc/fonts/conf.avail/35-ttf-arphic-ukai-aliases.conf
??5?????? c /etc/fonts/conf.avail/41-arphic-ukai.conf
??5?????? c /etc/fonts/conf.avail/41-ttf-arphic-ukai.conf
??5?????? c /etc/fonts/conf.avail/65-fonts-arphic-ukai.conf
??5?????? c /etc/fonts/conf.avail/75-arphic-ukai-select.conf
??5?????? c /etc/fonts/conf.avail/75-ttf-arphic-ukai-select.conf
??5?????? c /etc/fonts/conf.avail/90-arphic-ukai-embolden.conf
??5?????? c /etc/fonts/conf.avail/90-ttf-arphic-ukai-embolden.conf
```

I don't have a lot of knowledge, only NetworkManager is familiar. So I went to see the file, here is the output:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
enabled=true
```

Most lines are ended in files with .conf final. So, there is a problem with configuration files? There is not wrong apparently with the NetworkManager.conf, so why is it shown?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no problem with conf files. `dpkg --verify` is automatically set to display outputs upon testing file authenticity and checking for problems.